# Autofocus is not working for my Nikon AF-S 70-200mm f/2.8 SWM VR IF ED G

Tags: nikon, autofocus

I bought used lens (Nikon AF-S 70-200mm f/2.8 SWM VR IF ED G) from eBay. Not sure why Auto focus is not working. I tried outdoor photoshoot with 
1/100 f3.2 102mm ISO 100. This is VR1 lens.
I tried with and without tripod and I have Nikon D600 body. Lens contacts looks good to me. Please let me if I miss anything. 
AF and VR switch is ON. Distance is around 5 meters.

Comment: You mean it fails to take the shot in great focus, or there is no evidence that it even tries to focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the lens may be faulty or broken.

That lens should autofocus with that camera. Even with the focus limiter switch set to '∞-3m' it should be able to focus on a subject 5 meters away.

Assuming your outdoor shoot is during daylight hours and your focus target has sufficient contrast there is no reason why the lens should not be autofocusing correctly.

Here are a few things to try before concluding the lens is faulty:

- Try another lens on the same camera in the same shooting conditions with the same subject. Does the other lens autofocus properly?
- Just to be on the safe side, set the focus limiter switch to 'Full' (Your 5 meter estimate may actually be just below 3 meters).
- Aim at a very high contrast target. Does the lens AF then?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Michael. I did photoshoot during daylight. I have 14-24mm and 50mm lens for both the lenses autofocus is working properly. I will try to set the limiter to switch to 'Full' and let you know the result.

Comment: It worked after setting focus limiter switch to full. Thanks!